# NSwag: Map byte[] to ArrayBuffer or Blob on TypeScript-Client

Tags: javascript, c#, json, typescript, nswag

Using [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag):
Is there a way to change the primitive type mapping for a sub-type?
I'm using .NET FRAMEWORK.

E.g. having a controller method:

```
[Route("photos/upload")]
[HttpPost]    
public async Task<ResponseDTO<Guid>> UploadPhoto([FromBody] UploadPhotoRequestDTO content) {}
```

---

**My DTO:**

```
public class UploadPhotoRequestDTO
    {
        public Guid ID{ get; set; }
        public byte[] PhotoBytes { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Generated DTO:**

```
export class UploadPhotoRequestDTO implements IUploadPhotoRequestDTO {
    private _id!: string;
    private _photoBytes?: string | null;
}
```

***When generating the TypeScript client with NSwag it always generates a string | null property for the byte[].***

Nevertheless, I would need an ArrayBuffer or Blob instead. Is there a way to get the correct mapping?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: JSON has no representation of `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`. Since the NSwag DTOs represent the shape of the JSON response, when desterilized via `JSON.parse`, the code you are suggesting that it generate would be invalid/misleading. On a related note, make sure you configure NSwag to generate your TS DTOs as `interface`s instead of `class`es.

Comment: All DTOs are generated as interfaces, I just modified the code for brevity but thanks for the suggestion. 

To clarify what my goal is: I basically just want to upload a file (= getting a Blob/ArrayBuffer from native code) with some metadata that's why I think a multipart-form upload might be the way to go. Therefore, I'm submitting the file as blob.

Comment: as FormData accepts a blob, there should be a way to map a byte[] to a blob object with NSwag.

Comment: Yes, but  NSwag is generating your types with the assumption that they represent deserialized JSON. In the case of form data, you will not be uploading an object with a Blob property but rather the blob will _be_  your body. I think what you actually want is for your NSwag Http Client service, if you are generating one, to take a `Blob` typed parameter in the method it generates to call the `api/photos/upload` route. As you say, `multipart-form` is proper, but that implies a sending data in a different format/manner.

Comment: Consider `fetch(baseUrl +'/photos/upload', {method: 'POST', body: myFormData})` vs.  `fetch(baseUrl + '/photos/upload', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ photoBytes: myFormData })})`

Comment: You are right, that's another way to go. Nevertheless, I need some sort of property within my liquid-file to distinguish between text/plain and multipart requests. Is there a way to e.g. annotate my controller method to generate the correct code or any property I can access within the liquid file to write the logic myself?

Comment: I'm not familiar with LiquidFile. I know in Asp.NET Core, there is the `ConsumesAttribute`, i.e. `[Consumes("multipart-form-data")]`, but I don't know of anything equivalent in WebAPI 2. I would just handle this endpoint explicitly.

Comment: Would be great yeah, but both the IFormFile and the consumes/produces annotation are not part of the .NET Framework. In .NET Framework I need to directly parse the request within the controller method (at least as far as I know).

Comment: Something like `var parts = from part in (await this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()).Contents where part.Headers?.ContentType != null select part; foreach(var part in parts) { var fileBytes = await part.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); }`. Otherwise, you need to use the static `HttpContext`.

Comment: As mentioned before, the backend is not the issue. I already have everything in place. I just want to have the correct auto-generated client code for multipart-requests. But thank you anyway.